# Two Appium selectors, only one of them accepts text

Tags: javascript, android, appium, appium-android

I am trying to find a text box on the Android device using Appium and then type some text into it.

This works:

```
const login_field = await driver.$('android=new UiSelector().resourceId("my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email")');
await login_field.setValue("12345678");
```

This does not work (finds the element, then throws "login_field.setValue is not a function"):

```
const login_field = await driver.findElement("id", "my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email");
await login_field.setValue("12345678");
```

I performed some tracing on both strategies:

id (console log):

```
[0-0] 2019-08-05T06:49:03.157Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("id", "my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email")
[0-0] 2019-08-05T06:49:03.158Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb/element
[0-0] 2019-08-05T06:49:03.158Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'id', value: 'my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email' }
[0-0] 2019-08-05T06:49:11.577Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '7fe8b296-0ea5-4ffb-9450-12245de54bfa',
  ELEMENT: '7fe8b296-0ea5-4ffb-9450-12245de54bfa' }
```

Appium server:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb/element
[HTTP] {"using":"id","value":"my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email"}
[debug] [W3C (6357f0a4)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email","6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 10000 ms for condition
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/session/85f9a408-10f4-41dc-8a26-27f7ec98f874/element] with body: {"strategy":"id","selector":"my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email","context":"","multiple":false}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"85f9a408-10f4-41dc-8a26-27f7ec98f874","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"7fe8b296-0ea5-4ffb-9450-12245de54bfa"}}
[debug] [W3C (6357f0a4)] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"7fe8b296-0ea5-4ffb-9450-12245de54bfa","ELEMENT":"7fe8b296-0ea5-4ffb-9450-12245de54bfa"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb/element 200 8407 ms - 137
```

UiSelector (console log):

```
[0-0] 2019-08-05T06:49:11.579Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("-android uiautomator", "new UiSelector().resourceId("my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email")")
[0-0] 2019-08-05T06:49:11.580Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb/element
[0-0] 2019-08-05T06:49:11.580Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: '-android uiautomator',
  value:
   'new UiSelector().resourceId("my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email")' }
[0-0] 2019-08-05T06:49:11.776Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '88ee4e4f-e3dd-4068-91d6-c26860e538b4',
  ELEMENT: '88ee4e4f-e3dd-4068-91d6-c26860e538b4' }
```

Appium server:

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb/element
[HTTP] {"using":"-android uiautomator","value":"new UiSelector().resourceId(\"my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email\")"}
[debug] [W3C (6357f0a4)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["-android uiautomator","new UiSelector().resourceId(\"my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email\")","6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 10000 ms for condition
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://localhost:8200/wd/hub/session/85f9a408-10f4-41dc-8a26-27f7ec98f874/element] with body: {"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"new UiSelector().resourceId(\"my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email\")","context":"","multiple":false}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"85f9a408-10f4-41dc-8a26-27f7ec98f874","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"88ee4e4f-e3dd-4068-91d6-c26860e538b4"}}
[debug] [W3C (6357f0a4)] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"88ee4e4f-e3dd-4068-91d6-c26860e538b4","ELEMENT":"88ee4e4f-e3dd-4068-91d6-c26860e538b4"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb/element 200 194 ms - 137
```

Using different resources, I tried the following functions:

- addValue
- setValue
- sendKeys
- type

As you can expect, none of them was working.

My question is **If I am correct, I am referring the same element in both strategies (6357f0a4-ecc2-4e45-be55-c16a6ccfedcb), so why setValue is working only on UiSelector *and not on id*?**

I see that I receive two different IDs for the search results:

- 7fe8b296-0ea5-4ffb-9450-12245de54bfa
- 88ee4e4f-e3dd-4068-91d6-c26860e538b4

but I assume that it's because those IDs are assigned dynamically to the elements found using Appium.

I also tried to click the element before typing into the textbox - nope, the textbox cannot be clicked (using id strategy):

**"driver.findElement(...).click is not a function"**

Bonus:

I needed to get a message from toast notification and the only way to get it is to use XPATH, which is available for the findElement("xpath") and not for UiSelector. Although the toast notification is found using the following command:

```
const toast = await driver.findElement("xpath", "//android.widget.Toast[1]");
```

I am still not able to extract the text from it:

```
toast.text => undefined

toast.getAttribute("name") => "toast.getAttribute is not a function"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time with the documentation and other web pages and came up with the following solution:

```
const login_field2 = await driver.findElement("id", "my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email");
await driver.setValueImmediate(login_field2.ELEMENT, "12345678");
```

This is a better solution because you can use different selector strategies (including XPATH!):

```
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
```

However, I still need to find a way to extract other properties of the elements that I found, e.g. the toast notification text...

EDIT: One more method to my library:

```
const login_field = await driver.$('id=my.fancy.app:id/input_login_email');
await login_field.setValue("99999999");
```

FINAL EDIT:

There are two different strategies that can be used to access elements using WDIO, Appium and Android Native application:

- Selenium Remote (?) way:

  driver.findElement()
- WebdriverIO way:

  driver.$()

I was able to get the Android toast message by executing the following commands:

```
const toast = await driver.findElement("xpath", "//android.widget.Toast[1]");
const toastText = await driver.getElementAttribute(toast.ELEMENT, "text")
expect(toastText).to.equal("Toast text")
```

Using WebdriverIO way I was not able to find the element with XPATH selector, as Webdriver translates the XPATH using normalize-space() and add the dot before:

```
COMMAND findElement("xpath", ".//xpath[normalize-space() = "//android.widget.Toast"]")
[POST] http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session/98ba717f-e28f-4497-a280-74c55aa57c43/element
DATA { using: 'xpath', value: './/xpath[normalize-space() = "//android.widget.Toast"]' }
```